# A method for graphing the following set in two dimensions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

Consider the following set

$M =\left\{(x, y); x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 2 \leq -4-4x-4y-x^{2}-y^{2} \right\}$

How would you go about simplifying the equation?

I have come this far:

$x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 2 \leq -(x+2)^{2}-(y+2)^{2}+4$

Have I taken a wrong turn somewhere? The question is then to graph the set (I have peeked at the answer, so I know that it is in fact a single point.)

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. You are almost done: split the inequalities
$$x^{2}+y^{2} \color{blue}{\leq} 2 \color{red}{\leq} -(x+2)^{2}-(y+2)^{2}+4$$
in two and sketch the following sets:
$$D_1:=\{(x,y):x^{2}+y^{2} \color{blue}{\leq} 2\}\;\text{and}\;  D_2:=\{(x,y):(x+2)^{2}+(y+2)^{2}\color{red}{\leq} 4-2=2\}.$$
The set $M$ is the intersection $D_1\cap D_2$.

Comment: That's very clever, thanks Robert!